# where are the transpiled js files when using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular5

In an angular 5 project created by the help of the Angular CLI 1.5.0, when I run the following command

```
ng serve
```

I can see that web pack starts its bundling and projects starts serving. Where does the generated transpiled js file go to? Initially I thought this location should be the one mentioned in

tsconfig.json , OutDir

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

but funnily enough I can't seem to find that outdir folder inside the project folder.
I've also checked the angular-cli.json file

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      ......
      ......
```

but I still can't find the transpiled js files. What am I missing or doing wrong? Where are the java-script files for my .ts files?

Comment: When using ng serve, the transpiled files are held in memory, not on disk.  To generate the transpiled files for deployment etc, use ng build.

Comment: That definitely explains why those js files are not there. Thanks.

Comment: How does the browser locate these in-memory files?

Comment: The browser doesnt do that.  It sends (http get) requests to the embedded webserver (ng serve) which then serves those requests (replies with the in-memory files).

Answer (score 2):

`ng serve` keeps transpiled files in memory and does not write to disk. You need to do `ng build --watch` to get it to write to disk and also update with changes.